# Java, sum range of numbers in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Sorry I have been trying to figure this out and it's driving me crazy.

I need to write a java program that sums a range of numbers entered by the user and by the count of numbers entered by a user.  So if a user enters 5, 25 with count of 5.  It should sum 5+10+15+20+25=75  I have gotten it to work with a while loop, but not a for loop.  Sorry if I am asking for help for something that should be simple.  I left school almost 15 years ago involuntarily and struggling to get back into in.

Do I need to nest the loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class example1

{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int s, e, c = 0, sum = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a starting number:  ");
    s = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter an end number:  ");
    e = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a count by number:  ");
    c = sc.nextInt();

    {

      for (; s <= e; s++)
        sum += c;
      System.out.println("Sum of your numbers  " + sum);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `s` by one with `s++`, sounds like you should be incrementing by the count:

```
for (; s <= e; s+=c)
    sum += s;
```

Comment: Ah, I feel so dumb.  Thanks a lot.  Plus I put the for loop inside brackets.  That was my other error.

Comment: @RxEngery putting the loop in brackets isn't an error;  it's just unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you are asking. but follows show the method with for loop and while loop

```
 int i=2;
   while(i<c){
         System.out.println("Enter "+i+ " number :" );
         sum += sc.nextInt();
         i++;               
    }
```

for loop =>

```
for(int i=2; i< c ; i++){
       System.out.println("Enter "+i+ " number :" );
        sum += sc.nextInt();

   }

   System.out.println("Count : "+ (sum+s+e));
```

Comment: What atomSmasher put below helped me...That was 99% of my issue.    Other than I had an extra set of {} around the loop that wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the final code looked like and it worked with several different numbers I entered.  Is there a way to make this as "answered"?

```js
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class example1
  
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int s,e,c = 0, sum = 0;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter starting number:  ");
  s = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Enter an end number:  ");
  e = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Enter a count by number:  ");
  c = sc.nextInt();
  
      
      
    for (; s <= e; s+=c)
    sum += s;
    System.out.println("The sum of your number range is  " + sum);
    
    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class count

{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int s, e, c = 0, sum = 0,i=1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a starting number:  ");
    s = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter an end number:  ");
    e = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a count by number:  ");
    c = sc.nextInt();

    {
      for (i=s; i <= e; i+=c)
        sum += i;
      System.out.println("Sum of your numbers  " + sum);

    }

  }
}
```